# EditText not getting focussed

Tags: android, android-edittext

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_owner"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/comment_profilepic_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/comment_profilepic_height"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/newfeed_23" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_comment_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            style="@style/WhiteNormalText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_comment_textbox"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"

            android:hint="Post your comment..." />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Whenver I tap on the textbox, it gets focussed initially and then loses. I seriously have no idea what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try adding setFocus = "true" in xml

Answer (score 0):

try this on your .xml file:

```
<EditText
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/editComment"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        style="@style/WhiteNormalText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_comment_textbox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"

        android:hint="Post your comment..." />
```

on your activity:

```
EditText editComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editComment);
editComment.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

hope this helps you

Comment: no still does not work. Is it the focusable problem or something else